# Can not inject repository with constructor in Spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, dependency-injection

When I try to inject UserRepository in Constructor, I receive below error:
Cannot invoke "com.kiet.UserRepository.findAll()" because "this.userRepository" is null]

here is my code

UserRepository.java

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Integer> {}
```

UserJpaResource.java

```
@RestController
public class UserJpaResource {
    private UserRepository userRepository;
    private PostRepository postRepository;

    public UserJpaResource() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public UserJpaResource(UserRepository userRepository, PostRepository postRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
        this.postRepository = postRepository;
    }

    @GetMapping("/jpa/users")
    public List<User> retrieveAllUsers() {
        return userRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

When I get /jpa/users, I received this error
Cannot invoke "com.kiet.UserRepository.findAll()" because "this.userRepository" is null]

I want to inject UserRepository in UserJpaResource constructor
(don't using Annotation @Autowired)
please help me :(((

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring will only autowire your beans to a constructor that is not annotated with `@Autowired`, if it is the *only* constructor available in the class. Hence, you need to remove the no-args constructor. Check [the docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#using.spring-beans-and-dependency-injection) for more information on this.